# Get some attribute in a row on a table using jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a table in html like this :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="table1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.  </th>
        <th>No Request</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>Complaint</th>                                            
        <th>Estimation</th>                                            
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>   
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">1.  </td>

        <td class="sorting1" id='no_request' data-id-reseh="001">TMS/IT/04/001</td>

        <td class="center">Erika</td>

        <td class="center">06-04-2015, 18:26 </td>

        <td class="center" id="description">Erika yang minta</td>                                            

        <td class="center">06-04-2015, 18:56 </td>                                            

        <!-- Action-action -->
        <td  class="center">
            <a class="btn btn-info" id="btn-edit" name="edit"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" role="button" title="Beri Keterangan Request No. 1">
                <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i>
                Comment
            </a>

            <a class="btn btn-warning" >
                <i class="halflings-icon white arrow-up" id="print" email="tmsmkt1@tresnamuda.co.id"></i>
                Approve 
            </a>         
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="center">2.  </td>

        <td class="sorting1" id='no_request' data-id-reseh="002">TMS/IT/04/002</td>

        <td class="center">Ullinawati</td>

        <td class="center">06-04-2015, 18:27 </td>

        <td class="center" id="description">Ullie yang minta</td>                                            

        <td class="center">06-04-2015, 18:57 </td>                                            

        <td  class="center">
            <a class="btn btn-info" id="btn-edit" name="edit"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" role="button" title="Beri Keterangan Request No. 2">
                <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i>
                Comment
            </a>

            <a class="btn btn-warning" >
                <i class="halflings-icon white arrow-up" id="print" email="ullie@tresnamuda.co.id"></i>
                Approve 
            </a>         
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

My question is, can I grep attribute "email" based on the row of the table.
So lets say, in first row is = "tmsmkt1@tresnamuda.co.id" and the second row will be ="ullie@tresnamuda.co.id".
I make some code of jquery like this :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-warning").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        var idStr = $this.attr("email");

        console.log($this.attr('email')); // Failed
        console.log(idStr); // failed too

    });
```

Thanks for the help ...

Comment: In addition to the answers, it's good practice to prepend custom attributes with "data-" e.g. data-email="ullie@tresnamuda.co.id". This will prevent any future conflicts with new HTML specifications and also helps with readability, validation etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since `email` attribute is attached with the element `i` which is the child element of `btn-warning`, you need to use `find()`

```
$(".btn-warning").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).find("i").attr('email')); 
});
```

`find()` will get the child elements.
[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoship/51fevoam/11/)

Answer (score 0):

As ids are unique in the page so as i can see in your page you have applied same ids to multiple elements *`(i)`* it to the elements, so this causes a ***invalid markup generation***. in this case i suggest you to remove the id attribute and place it in the class names:

```
<i class="halflings-icon white arrow-up print" email="tmsmkt1@tresnamuda.co.id"></i>
```

and then you can target it like:

```
var idStr = $this.find('.print').attr("email");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use children() function to find `i` element

```
$(".btn-warning").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).children("i").attr('email'));
});
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/51fevoam/12/